# Bluetooth is not turning on in Ubuntu 16.04 after reinstallation

Tags: bluetooth

I need your help in activation of my Bluetooth.Before the reinstallation it was working properly.  Now its not connecting and even doesn't search any adapter.

[image]

Please help me to get it resolve.

Comment: What hardware do you use? Please add output of `uname -a`, `lspci -v | grep -E -A8 "Bluetooth|Wireless|Network"` and `rfkill list` to the question.

Comment: Hi N0rbert, Thanks for response, here is output of above command.....     aryabhatta@aryabhatta-Lenovo-E40-80:~$ uname -a
Linux aryabhatta-Lenovo-E40-80 4.15.0-24-generic #26~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 15 14:35:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: aryabhatta@aryabhatta-Lenovo-E40-80:~$ lspci -v | grep -E -A8 
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
aryabhatta@aryabhatta-Lenovo-E40-80:~$ lspci -v | grep -E -A8 "Bluetooth|Wireless|Network"
09:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless

Comment: Network Adapter (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
 Memory at c3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
 Expansion ROM at c3080000 [disabled] [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k

Comment: Network Adapter (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
 Memory at c3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
 Expansion ROM at c3080000 [disabled] [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k